# how to add a data-source attribute for x-editable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, x-editable

How, in rails, do you supply a dynamic hash to the source data attribute that x-editable accepts?

```
  <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-type="select" data-pk="<%= g.id %>" data-model="graded_item" data-name="teacher_grade_id" data-url="<%= graded_item_url(g) %>" data-source="<%= g.gradescale.grade_scale_items.map{ |x| "{x.id, x.grade}" } %>" data-title="Edit Grade">

      <%= g.teacher_grade.try(:grade) %> - <%= g.teacher_grade.try(:name) %>
  </a>
```

The docs want a hash like `{ value: id, text: name }` but I can't seem to get a hash that doesn't result in a red inactive select menu (x-editable doesn't like the source).

Anyone have an example of a dynamic data-source for x-editable in rails?

Per docs

If array - it should be in format: `[{value: 1, text: "text1"}, {value: 2, text: "text2"}, ...]`

For compatibility, object format is also supported: `{"1": "text1", "2": "text2" ...}` but it does not guarantee elements order.

## update

This created an instance variable that is an array of hashes in the exact format the docs says is needed for an array data-source.  But, this also results in an error empty select in the editable popup.

```
  @grade_scale_items = []
  @course.gradescale.grade_scale_items.each do |x| 
      @grade_scale_items << {value: x.id, text: "#{x.grade} - #{x.name}"}
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple fix...after digging a bit.  The docs aren't real helpful with this, and the rails examples only uses text fields (no select menus).  Convert the array of hashes to json...like so.

```
  @grade_scale_items = []
  @course.gradescale.grade_scale_items.each do |x| 
     @grade_scale_items << {value: x.id, text: "#{x.grade} - #{x.name}"}
  end

  view: data-source="<%= @grade_scale_items.to_json %>"
```

This puts it in a format that x-editable is happy with as a data-source